# How to add another authorization-filter to a url that is already protected by Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot application protected with `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Now i want to add another (custom) way of authentication for certain endpoints. Therefore i created a class extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and `AuthenticationProvider` with its custom logic. Now i want to add the custom filter to the HttpSecurity object in my security-configuration with

```
http.addFilterBefore(new VendorSessionAuthorizationFilter(), KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class);
```

My understanding is that i get to my custom filter first and depending on the result, the security-filter-chain goes on to the Keycloak-Filters. When i test to call an endpoint i never get to the `attemptAuthentication` method i implemented in my filter.
I have the feeling that no matter what i do when calling `http.addFilterBefore(...` the Keycloak-Filters are always executed so there is no way for me to have another way of authentication.

Here the SecurityConfiguration:

````
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class KeycloakSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http.addFilterBefore(new VendorSessionAuthorizationFilter(), KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class);
        http.authenticationProvider(new VendorSessionAuthenticationProvider());

        http
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
                .and().formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilterBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilterBean(
            KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}

```
````

Comment: **Do not use Keycloak adapters for Spring**, [it is (very) deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). Alternatives [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an alternative auth method for certain endpoints, there is a way as below

at the `configure` part of the adapter, you can add an `antMatcher` and reference a function of a bean. You can place the function in the same class

```
.antMatchers("/your-api-here")
.access("@keycloakSecurityConfiguration.checkSomething()")
```

Your total configuration would be something like below (adapt properly)

```
public class KeycloakSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);

    http.addFilterBefore(new VendorSessionAuthorizationFilter(), KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class);
    http.authenticationProvider(new VendorSessionAuthenticationProvider());

    http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatchers("/your-api-here") 
            .access("@keycloakSecurityConfiguration.checkSomething()")

            .....
}

public boolean checkSomething(){

    // your code here
}
```

**NOTE** This will override the default keycloak auth for the api, not provide an extra one on top